# in GreasePencil, how to add inbetween frames like the F5-key in Adobe Animate?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

Is there a way to easily add inbetween frames, without using the mouse and moving everything by hand?
Like the F5 key in Adobe Animate?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate what F5 does for non adobe users?

Comment: Are you talking about _Interpolate Sequence_?

Comment: @brockmann basically F5 adds a space in front of your keyframe. So if you want a keyframe to last 2 frames or more, you just press F5.
It is very covenant to adjust your timing while drawing, without having to use the mouse and going in the timeline.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett no no I don't talk about the interpolation tweens. I just want to quickly make the dark bar that is between the keyframes longer. You know what I mean?

Comment: AFAIK you can't, but it's totally possible to do this with python scripting

Comment: Too bad, I don't know anything about Python. Thanks @Tomreggae for letting me know

Comment: I wrote an addon that makes this a bit faster: https://github.com/bergamote/greaspencil_nudge_frames

Comment: @wilks EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED! Thankx